# Spring boot with Thymeleaf static assets getting repetitive log statements

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm converting from JSPs to Thymeleaf while converting a SOA service to Spring Boot.  I'm wondering if I have not configured something correctly as I continue to get these statements:

```
o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /css/bootstrap.min.css
o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /img/gizmonicInstitute.jpg
o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/img/gizmonicInstitute.jpg]
o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/css/bootstrap.min.css]
```

Within my .html file (located within the /resources/templates directory)

```
<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
      href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
.
:
<img src="/img/gizmonicInstitute.jpg"/>
```

With in my spring boot startup, I see ResourceHttpRequestHandler mapped as follows:

```
o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

Is there something I'm not configuring?  The pages are being discovered and are rendering fine.. just that these messages are littering my logs.

Comment: Those log messages are at debug level so they should be disabled by default. Having you changed the logging configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that the existing SLF/Logback configuration which we had in an logback.xml file enabled root to be level info:

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="central"/>
</root>
```

Requiring a configuration level set for spring:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.*: WARN
```

Once I set the configuration level to WARN or above, these messages disappeared (which I interpreted as a misconfiguration with my spring boot migration).  Shout out to @AndyWilkinson for directing my attention toward log messaging levels.

**Update #1**

A note that once the logback.xml is used, setting configuration level via properties does not seem to work.  So I had to add this to logback.xml:

```
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
```